ASCII to integer: can not distinguish between error and 0 (0x30) when using atoi
atoi returns zero (0x00) for number 0 (0x30)
It also returns zero (0x00) for an error.
How do I tell which is which?
// In both QT and GCC i is:
int i = atoi("0");    // 0 (should be success)
int i = atoi("NON");  // 0 (should be failure)
int i = atoi("1");    // 1 (success)


Please provide a [mcve]. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Is there a function like atoi that returns bool to determine whether it was successful or not and modifies variable from a pointer as a result. Or vice versa?

It is documented, see: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atol.3.html#BUGS

@mike "int i = atoi("NON");  // 0 (should be failure)" --> the code comment is incorrect.  atoi() is not specified that it should fail in this case.  Returning 0 is fine.  Research strtol() or use str2i().

@yurich Yes, if (sscanf("NON", "%d", &i) == 1) Success(); is close to OP's need (it may have overflow issues with "9876543210").
